# C++ passing a typedef

Tags: c++

I was wondering how I would pass a typedef into a function. For example:

```
    typedef int box[3][3];
    box empty, *board[3][3];
```

How would I pass board onto a function? Also inside the function parameter can I use decltype()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would do this:

```
using box = std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 3>;
```

and then:

```
void fn(box const& x)
void fn(box& x)
void fn(box&& x)
```

or whatever you need for it.

And yes, you can use `decltype` just fine in the function.

As a practical example, you could define a function that prints the contents of the box:

```
using box = std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 3>;

void fn(box const& arr) {
    for (auto const& x : arr) {
        for (auto i : x) {
            std::cout << i << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

and then just call it with:

```
int main() {
    box x {{
        {1, 2, 3},
        {4, 5, 6},
        {7, 8, 9}
    }};
    fn(x);
}
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc0d087d00ef9920)

Comment: Hmm so your declaration would be equivalent to creating the box[3][3], now how would I do the same for a array of size 3x3 that points to said boxes

Comment: Once you have the type synonim `box`, you can pretty much treat it like any other type. So a pointer to a 3x3 collection of boxes would be `std::array<std::array<box, 3>, 3>`.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try it out, and return if I have any lingering questions

Answer (score 1):

If you need to pass a typedef into a function, then try declaring your structure outside of the function.  This will give it a global scope and consequently make it available to the function.

i.e. this:

```
void func(test, test); // parameter name warning occurs here

int main()
{
   typedef struct{
      int a, b, c;
   } test;
   test here, there;

   //.........

   func(here, there);

   return 0;
}

void func(test here, test there) // parse error occurs here
{
   //........
}
```

Would turn into this:

```
typedef struct{
      int a, b, c;
   } test;

void func(test, test); // parameter name warning occurs here

int main()
{

   test here, there;

   //.........

   func(here, there);

   return 0;
}

void func(test here, test there) // parse error occurs here
{
   //........
}
```

Comment: Correct me if my understanding is wrong, so inside my struct I would have the box[3][3], then inside the function parameter I would write box * board[3][3]